# How to inherit another object in opc-ua

Tags: python-3.x, opc-ua

I have a HomeBaseObjectType and a HomeRegionType in my type model as such:

[image]

This is my code in python using Freeopcua library:

```py
# create a new node type we can instantiate in our address space
    dev = await server.nodes.base_object_type.add_object_type(idx, "HomedBaseObjectType")
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "BadScanCounter", 1, ua.VariantType.Int64)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "DetectorTemp", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "Flow", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "LaserDC", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "LaserPP", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "Pressure", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "SingleBeamAt2500", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "SingleBeamAt900", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)
    await (await dev.add_variable(idx, "TempOptics", 0.0, ua.VariantType.Double)).set_modelling_rule(True)

    dev1 = await server.nodes.base_object_type.add_object_type(idx, "HomedRegionType")
    await (await dev1.add_object(idx, "HomeBaseObjectType")).set_modelling_rule(True)
```

How should i make the variables under HomedBaseObjectType appear under HomedRegionType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, we need to specify the objecttype during adding object:

```py
await (await dev1.add_object(idx, "HomedBaseObjectType", objecttype=dev)).set_modelling_rule(True)
```